# How to use properties in Inheritance with C#?

Tags: c#, properties

Please consider this code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("BaseClass\n"); }
    public virtual int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass\n"); }
    public override int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

How can I use `WorkProperty` ? frankly it seems useless .

With the main :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass A2 = new DerivedClass();

        int a = A2.WorkProperty;
        Console.WriteLine(a);

        // do more stuff with `a`                       

    }
}
```

On the other hand if I have something like this :

```
public class CoOrds
{
    private int x, y;

    public CoOrds()  // constructor
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }
}
```

Then `x` and `y` are data members , and here the properties are helpful.

So what's the purpose of the property in the first code ?

Thanx

Comment: It serves as base implementation for other subclasses that don't wish to override it (`virtual` allows overriding, `abstract` requires it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your properties meaningful it makes more sense when you override them. A virtual property provides a default that child classes can override when it makes sense for them to override them. See this PsudoStream class example.

```
class PsudoStream 
{
    public virtual bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
    public virtual bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
}

class WritableStream : PsudoStream 
{
    //CanRead is false already and does not need to be overwritten

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
}

class ReadableStream : PsudoStream 
{
    //CanWrite is false already and does not need to be overwritten

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**So what's the purpose of the property in the first code ?**

The purpose of giving the `WorkProperty` in the baseClass is that it acts as default property if none of the derivedClass overrides the property.

for example consider this code,

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("BaseClass\n"); }
    public virtual int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass\n"); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass A2 = new DerivedClass();

        int a = A2.WorkProperty;
        Console.WriteLine(a);              ***//output will be "0"***

        // do more stuff with `a`                       

    }
}
```

Here the output is "0" because it used the Defauklt WorkProperty in the baseClass because there was no overridden implementation found.